# problem with the injection of an EJB that resides in a jar

Tags: jar, ejb, code-injection

I have some problems regarding the EJB injection and I haven't been able to find a solution anywhere.
My situation is the following: I have an EAR file that includes a WAR and several JARs, all listed in the application.xml file. All is working fine for this part.
The problems come out when I try to add what we can call a “plugin system”. 
I have a JAR with inside some .xhtml pages, backing beans and EJBs. This JAR, if needed, is inserted inside the EAR in a specific directory (let's call it “plugins”) and is detected from the application at startup.
When the JAR is detected it's path is added to the WAR class loader so all the pages and the backing bean are detected without problems. What is not working is the injection of the EJBs (I tried to use the notation @EJB, @Inject, the lookup...). I can't inject any of the EJBs that is inside the JAR plugin.
My guess is that the application server treats the JAR as a simple library module and doesn't look for any EJB inside it, so they are inside the JAR but not usable from the application.

My question is: there's a way of having this working? I tried to add the JAR in the EAR's MANIFEST.MF but nothing changed...

---

the application server i'm using is glassfish 3.0. About the application.xml: there's no reference in it about the JARs that are part of what i called "plugin system". This because i detect them when i deploy (or i restart) the application in the application server, so they may or may not be inside the system and i don't really know that before the system is started.
Each plugin JAR is a "collection" of pages and functionalities that can be added or removed from the system dynamically (more less like a real plugin system).
My EAR structure is the following:

MyApp.EAR

- META-INF
- lib
- plugins

  - plugin1.JAR
- app.WAR
- logic1.JAR
- logic2.JAR

for example: in the application.xml i have the references for app.WAR, logic1.JAR and logic2.JAR (they are always inside the system), at startup the application looks inside the folder "plugins" for any plugin (specific JARs) to be added to the system.

I hope i've been more clear about what i'm trying to do...

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the EJB are not even registered in the JNDI tree of the server. Which application server are you using? You can have a look to this JNDI tree to see if the EJBs are there, but the way to do this depends on the specific server.

How are you declaring the JAR that contains the EJBs in the EAR application.xml?

It should be someting lide this:

```
<application>
  ....
  <module>
    <ejb>nameOfTheJarFile.jar</ejb>
  </module>
</application>
```

The Jar should be in a the "/lib" directory of the EAR.

I hope this helps.